# Python 3.6.1 install location

Tags: python-3.x, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Python 3.6.1 on my Ubuntu 16 server and cannot find the install location. I have looked in /usr/bin and there are reference to all other versions except 3.6.1. Where can I find the executable for this version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use command "whereis python3.6.1"

Comment: I did that and all I got was "python3.6:"

Answer (score 3):

In your terminal, type : `which python3`