# Where is Python 3.6.1 Located on my Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble finding where my Python 3.6.1 installation is located. I referenced this Stack Overflow post: [Python 3.6.1 install location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734164/python-3-6-1-install-location)

by using:

```
whereis python3.6.1
```

it doesn't return anything. Whereas I do:

```
whereis python
```

it returns:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

When I navigate to that location I only get my Python2 installation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `which python3` or `which python3.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `which python3`instead that should work